# Adding a button to a Cell - Logic Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have added a button in a cell, so if there are 10 cells there will be a button each per cell.

This is how i added the button to the cell

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [but addTarget:self 
                         action:@selector(submitReceiptButtonClicked:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    but.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,30);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:but];
```

when the this button is clicked, i will alert the user with a UIAlertView, If the User clicks OK in the AlertView, i need to change the text of that button to Done.

In the `clickedButtonAtIndex`

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

 NSString *name= [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

if([name isEqualToString:@"OK"])
        {

// Here i need to change the text of the Button (which is in a cell) to `Done`.

}
```

When the user clicks on the OK button of the UIAlertVIew, i need to change the text of the button to `Done` (This button, should belong to the cell that i clicked. Button in other cells should not change.)

Answer (score 0):

1 Set button tag to be the indexPath.row + aConstant

2 in submitReceiptButtonClicked:(id)sender read button tag and put it in to a global NSInteger

3 in alertView delegate  get the cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the indexPath will be     `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourSavedInteger - aConstant inSection:0];`  Then get the button from cell's content view `UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:yourSavedInteger];` and change button title.

Comment: SO in case the user performs a quick scroll, will it still work ?

Comment: to sch What will happen in the case that the cell is reused? You will change the title on a wrong cell.
to Illep Yes it will work but you have to cheep track in an array what buttons have changed, or the names for it. And in cellForRow read from that array. Because cells can be reused, but indexPath's will be diffrent